# Making a matrix from from unique values from two columns

Tags: pandas

I have dataset in this form:

```
data = {'col1':['a','a','b','c'],
        'col2':['d','e','f','g'],
        'col3':[1,2,3,4]}
pd.DataFrame(data)

   col1 col2 col3
0   a   d   1
1   a   e   2
2   b   f   3
3   c   g   4
```

But i want data to be of following form:

```
    d   e   f   g
a   1   1   0   0
b   0   0   1   0
c   0   0   0   1
```

Any help?

Comment: Any Try from your end?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)`

Comment: Thanks, what if i want to add same number as (2,3,4) instead of 1 at their places

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2, df.col3)`